# Fedora 21 update failed

Tags: linux, fedora, updates, fedora-21

I have fedora workstation 21 installed and I got a notification in the Software application about an "Important OS Update". When I click "restart and install", the machine restarts and boots into the installer splash screen. The progress "bubble" (the little loading fedora icon) barley gets started before it instantly goes to full and then restarts.

When I get back into my workstation, I get a notification that the "important OS update failed" and it gives me the following error:

```
The offline update failed in an unexpected way.
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

Failed to find NetworkManager;1:0.9.10.1-1.git20150105.fc21;x86_64;updates
```

(duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849397/fedora-21-update-failed , I had exactly the same problem )

Possible collision with `yum update`...

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried doing a yum update after this error message but the command line tells me that my system is up to date.

Comment: Same issue here :(

Comment: Are you running Fedora 21 _now_, or are you upgrading from 20 to 21?